# Get File when given Server File Location

Tags: vb.net, tfs

Is it possible to get the actual file, or the file that gets copied from version control to a location?

This sounds confusing. Basically I have the file path of the version controlled file, but I need an actual path to the file because I need to make a cconsole command using powershell.exe. The file will look something like this

```
$/MyTeamProject/MyProject/Development/MyPowershellScript.ps1
```

Now, I am looking for a vb expression to see if I can get the actual file and make call the powershell.exe command from console. Any thoughts?

Comment: You know the server path of a file and you want to get the latest version of that file to local disk. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes I do. I'm creating a build in TFS of which I provide a server path to a ps1 file and then I use the InvokeProcess activity to call powershell as a command line command. Unfortunately, the server path doesn't point to a physical file and so I need to get the latest version and then pass that to my command line command.

Comment: This is what we do in PowerShell (wrapped in other code):
foreach ($item in Get-TfsChildItem $ServerBranchLocation -recurse -server $tfs)  
{ & "$TF" get $item.ServerItem /force /noprompt }

Comment: I can't use this. This is strictly in my build process template where the InvokeProcess activity forms the command line call. I can't pass in a server path because it doesn't point to a physical file. What I would need to do is get a copy of the physical file and pass it to my command. I would have to figure out how to achieve this. The answer in this question that @Dono proposed may be a solution, but I would need to figure it out in my build process template

Comment: Godd luck, hope you figure it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use VersionControlServer.GetItem(String path) to obtain a reference to the Item. Then use Item.DownloadFile() or Item.DownloadFile(String localPath) to copy the file locally. I have a variation of this that creates a shipment based on multiple changesets.

Comment: This looks great and I've been trying to get this to work in my TFS Build Process template but no dice. I'll see if I can find a way to implement this.